# Does git log --branches work?

Tags: git

I can't seem to get `git log --branches` to correctly filter its output. It seems as if Git ignores it.

For example, the head of `git log --graph --all --decorate`, prints:

```
* commit 3ae0d17538f787bdde68f37f6644ffe9652d8dc1 (HEAD, feature/branch-ignore)
| Author: Chris Lewis <chris@chris.to>
| Date:   Mon Mar 14 17:39:56 2011 -0700
| 
|     Ignore merge commits, as they're going to be duplicating events
|  
* commit 770534e9d77acb03eaf842440c879aec1c5b5500
| Author: Chris Lewis <chris@chris.to>
| Date:   Tue Mar 8 14:39:40 2011 -0800
| 
|     Removed another remote branch check
|
```

Let's say I want to filter by `master`, which should mean these commits are ignored. The head of `git log --graph --all --decorate --branches=master`, is also:

```
* commit 3ae0d17538f787bdde68f37f6644ffe9652d8dc1 (HEAD, feature/branch-ignore)
| Author: Chris Lewis <chris@chris.to>
| Date:   Mon Mar 14 17:39:56 2011 -0700
| 
|     Ignore merge commits, as they're going to be duplicating events
|  
* commit 770534e9d77acb03eaf842440c879aec1c5b5500
| Author: Chris Lewis <chris@chris.to>
| Date:   Tue Mar 8 14:39:40 2011 -0800
| 
|     Removed another remote branch check
|
```

Git doesn't seem to be filtering. It doesn't seem to make any difference whether `--branches` is passed with other arguments or not. My Git version is `git version 1.7.4.1`. Does anyone know how to use this command successfully?

EDIT: All I want to be able to do is get the log of one branch or another, without having to do a checkout first.

Comment: Interesting question. None of the comments below so far address what --branches is supposed to do or how it's supposed to work.

Comment: I have added an answer which now explains why it does work correctly even though it appeared not to be.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Firstly, (the other) Adam is right that it doesn't make sense to use `--all` for this: if you only want to see one branch like your question states, why ask for all branches?

Secondly, as already stated in comments to other answers, you don't need `--branches`; just do `git log mybranch`.

Thirdly, I can explain why `git log --branches=mybranch` doesn't work.  The [`git-log(1)` man page](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-log) says:

```
--branches[=<pattern>]
    Pretend as if all the refs in refs/heads are listed on
    the command line as <commit>. If <pattern> is given, 
    limit branches to ones matching given shell glob. If 
    pattern lacks ?, *, or [, /* at the end is implied.
```

The last sentence is the crucial point here.  If the `<pattern>` is just `mybranch` then there is no globbing character, so `git-log` interprets it as if you'd typed

```
git log --branches=mybranch/*
```

which only matches references under `$repo/.git/refs/heads/mybranch/*`, i.e. branches which begin with `mybranch/`.

There is a dirty hack to prevent the `/*` from being assumed:

```
git log --branches=[m]ybranch
```

but I can't think of any good reason why you would want to do this rather than just typing

```
git log mybranch
```

Comment: Then it's only one branch (git log mybranch) or all branches.  What if you want, say two branches.  --branches, one would think, would be the way to do it.  What is?

Comment: @Emmel `git log branch1 branch2`

Comment: I find it amusing that despite being nearly 100k of solid text the official docs for `git log` do not appear to mention that `git log branch` is a thing. https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log

Comment: @Neutrino, you were looking for [`<revision range>`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#Documentation/git-log.txt-ltrevisionrangegt) section

Comment: "<revision range> Show only commits in the specified revision range." That section doesn't mention branch at all.

Answer (score 15):

Because you specified `--all`, you override any branch specifications you made.

Comment: The lack of a warning seems to be a usability bug to me.

Comment: As I mentioned in the question, it doesn't seem to make any difference if I use other flags or not. `git log --branches=master` gives the same commits back (formatted differently, obviously). It just isn't working.

Comment: @Lewisham: If you want only master, use `git log master`.

Answer (score 12):

Let's say your history looked like this

```
  d -- e [refs/tags/release1]
 /
a -- b -- c [refs/heads/master]
      \
       f -- g [refs/heads/dev1]
        \
         h [refs/heads/dev2]
```

If you do `git log --branches` it's the same `git log master dev1 dev2`, so you'll see commits a,b,c,f,g and h. If you did `git log release1 --branches=dev*` it's the same as `git log release1 dev1 dev2`.  You'll see a,d,e,b,f,g, and h, but not c.

Comment: This example `git log master dev1 dev2` was helpful.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

## Explanation of `--branches`

`git log <commit>` lists all commits that are reachable from any `<commit>` that you list on the command line.

- `--all` does the same but pretends that you listed all the refs in `refs/`.
- `--branches[=<pattern>]` does the same but pretends that you listed all the refs in `refs/heads`. It also allows you to limit with a glob pattern. As a gotcha, if your glob pattern lacks `?`, `,` or `[`, then an `/` at the end is implied.

## Examples

`git log topic1 topic2 topic3`

means list all the commits reachable from `topic1`, `topic2`, or `topic3`.

`git log -all`

means list all the commits that are reachable from any of the refs that are output from `git show-ref`.

`git log --branches="topic*"`

means list all the commits that are reachable from from any branch that starts with the prefix `topic`.

## Sources

https://schacon.github.io/git/git-log.html

https://schacon.github.io/git/git-rev-list.html

Answer (score 3):

> Does anyone know how to use this command successfully?
>
> EDIT: All I want to be able to do is get the log of one branch or another, without having to do a checkout first.

In order to visualise the graph of commits on all branches and remotes do this:

```
$ git log --graph --branches=* --remotes=* --decorate
```

Use this with other `git-log` options to control verbosity, e.g. `--oneline`, `--name-status`, etc.

You may have to fetch remote changes first in order to see them. You can fetch all remote changes without applying them to your current branch(es) like this:

```
$ git fetch --all
```