# Does git log --branch have a different behaviour on normal and bare repositories?

Tags: git, logging, branch, git-bare

I'd like to use the git log command to extract the list of changes from a repository since a given date on a specified branch.

For the purpose I found the following syntax which seems to work fine:

```
git log --since=2011-10-01 --branches=mybranch
```

The above command works fine on a cloned repository in my workstation (Ubuntu 10.04, GIT 1.7.7.2) but outputs a wrong log on the main repository from which the clone has been created. The main repository is a bare GIT repository hosted on Centos 5.5, GIT 1.7.3.4. 
Basically, the main repository does not show a number of the most recent commits.

I don't understand if this is the expected behavior and the difference is due to the fact that the main repo is bare, or if this is a different behavior due to the fact that the GIT version is not the same.

Comment: And your most recent commits have all been pushed back to that remote bare repo?

Comment: Thanks for your help. I am not a committer on that repository, I just cloned it from the server to my local workstation. Tried the command in local and got a result, logged into the server via terminal, repeated the command on the same repository (no one committed anything on the server in between) and got a different result. Plus, it was the local clone to show more commits than the remote server.

Comment: Did yuo made any recent commit since you cloned that repo (and before doing those log commands)?

Comment: No, no changes. The flow is the following:
1. clone a remote bare repo
2. execute command above in the cloned repo
3. telnet to remote server
4. execute command above in the remote repo

No commmits in between

Comment: Instead of using `--branches`, did you try the same command with the branch name directly? (a bit like suggested in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5316802/does-git-log-branches-work)

Comment: Excellent. I have added an answer for more visibility on that command.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Following the suggestion of "[Does git log --branches work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5316802/does-git-log-branches-work)", I have suggested in the comments:

```
git log --since=2011-10-01 mybranch
```

I.e:

- using the name of the branch directly
- *not using* the `--branches` option when accessing the logs of a given branch.

The [OP giamma](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1053635/giamma) reports it works.