# how to filter git-branch by author

Tags: git

How can I list branches filter by (last) author name?

For example, I want to get only `main` and `mybranch` by filtering "yukihane" from following repository.

```
* commit 9315faf698c4f733e96047ffe65a636330a4edc1 (origin/others, others)
| Author: other <other@example.com>
| Date:   Tue Apr 19 09:00:50 2022 +0900
|
|     others
|
| * commit c37b840649c71080eb0705e6800f359a22c1183a (HEAD -> mybranch, origin/mybranch)
|/  Author: yukihane <yukihane@example.com>
|   Date:   Tue Apr 19 08:54:02 2022 +0900
|
|       my commit
|
* commit f4e0a4721a066d1777eb7a21efdf0ede3874a4e0 (origin/main, main)
  Author: yukihane <yukihane@example.com>
  Date:   Tue Apr 19 08:53:30 2022 +0900

      init
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
git log --branches --no-walk --author=yukihane
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is what the [documentation] says[1]:
[1]: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log

To filter by author:

> --author=
> --committer=
> Limit the commits output to ones with author/committer header lines that match the specified pattern (regular expression). With more than one --author=, commits whose author matches any of the given patterns are chosen (similarly for multiple --committer=).

To filter by branch:

> --branches[=]
> Pretend as if all the refs in refs/heads are listed on the command line as . If  is given, limit branches to ones matching given shell glob. If pattern lacks ?, *, or [, /* at the end is implied.

Other resources:

- Filtering by author: [How can I view a git log of just one user's commits?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4259996/how-can-i-view-a-git-log-of-just-one-users-commits)
- Filtering by branch: [Does git log --branches work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5316802/does-git-log-branches-work)

Although trying it now, I had issues getting the `--branches` option to work as I expected. The link above ^^^ may help.